# Sunspot search has_one association, other model has no foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sunspot, sunspot-rails

I'm using Sunspot Solr to search events and each event has a group_id that refers to a Group object (multiple events can have the same group). I want to find the right events if the user searches the group name.

Attempted solution in the searchable block

```
string :events_group_name do
  group.map(&:name)
end
```

Error

SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: groups.event_id: SELECT  "groups".* FROM "groups"  WHERE "groups"."event_id" = 3 LIMIT 1

Problem is that there is no event_id in Group, so how can I get this to work? The workaround is to save the group name as a column in the Event object, but surely there's a better way. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know anything about Sunspot, but I believe that your model is incorrectly mapped. If you have a association like:

> 1 Group -> N events

You should use a `has_many` and a `belongs_to` in your model. `has_one` is only used with associations 1 to 1. In your case:

```
class Group
  has_many :events
  #...
end

class Event
  belongs_to :group
  #...
end
```

The Rails Guide has a [good article](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) about Active Record associations with examples. You can take a look at it.

Comment: Thanks a ton! I figured it out, first we change it to belongs_to as per your suggestion (stupid stupid me) and then in the searchable block add, text :group do group.name if group end (to check if group is nil)